# how to store the default Jlabel icon into database when the user not selected the photo

Tags: java, swing

I have a small requirement please help me
Firstly, I have a label, i set a icon to that label as

lbl_photo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                "/images/photo.png")));

and i have a button browse to select the image.

```
private void btn_browseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "jpeg, gif and png files", "jpg", "gif", "png");
    int i = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (i == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        image = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        try {
            BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(image);
            int type = originalImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
                    : originalImage.getType();
            BufferedImage resizeImageJpg = resizeImage(originalImage, type);
            photo = new ImageIcon(toImage(resizeImageJpg));
            raster = resizeImageJpg.getRaster();
            data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        lbl_photo.setIcon(photo);
    }
}
```

now, I am storing the selected image from browse button into  database

```
                    Date date1 = new Date();
            Timestamp timestamp1 = new Timestamp(date1.getTime());
            String sql4 = "insert into std_photos values(?,?,?)";
            pstmt5 = con.prepareStatement(sql4);
            pstmt5.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txt_eno.getText()));
            pstmt5.setString(2, "");
            pstmt5.setTimestamp(3, timestamp1);
            byte[] extractBytes = data.getData();
            pstmt5.setBytes(2, extractBytes);
            System.out.println(sql4);
```

image is successfully storing.but,if the user doesn't select the image through browse button the default jlabel icon should be store in the database.
please help me as early as possible

Answer (score 0):

You are already checking the return value of `chooser.showOpenDialog(this)` for `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`.

In case you receive some other option or if the `try-catch` block reading the new image fails you could just get the old icon and write it into the database.